# ARCore transformCoordinates2d() Results from View to CPU image?

Tags: android, arcore

I can get 2D - 3D correspondences from the ARCore world points to the view.

I am using a Google Pixel 2 that has a 1440 by 2880 resolution. My 2D points are in that coordinate system.

I want the same points transformed in the CPU image.

There are 2 issues here:

The CPU image (640 by 480) is rotated 90 degrees counter-clock wise.
The function transformCoordinates2d() I am using is:

```
frame.transformCoordinates2d(Coordinates2d.VIEW, xyVIEW, Coordinates2d.IMAGE_PIXELS, xyCPU);
```

From the VIEW to the IMAGE_PIXELS (CPU).

Is the input to the *transformCoordinates2d()* function [x,y,xy ... ] ? And the output the same ?

When I then try to plot the points on the CPU image I get random values.

Also Coordinates2d VIEW says in the docs that it is *"Android view, display-rotated, (x,y) in pixels."*. So does that mean it takes into account the 90 degrees ?